# Should canonical tags point to the guest post on an external site, or the copy on my own site?

Tags: seo, canonical-url, rel-canonical, link-building, guest-blogging

I'm guest posting on a blog related to my niche. The end result would be fresh new content for the blog, and I get a back link to my blog.

I'm also planning on posting the same article on my own site.

I was wondering what is the best way to use canonical tags for this written content? Should I make the article on my site the original, and the guest post the duplicate?

I'm new to guest posting hopefully you can give me some tips.

Comment: I thought that the point of guest posting is that you wouldn't publish a copy of the article yourself.   The deal is that the other place gets original, non-duplicated content, and you get a link.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller While that's how it usually works, it does very much depend on the agreement with the other party.

Answer (score 3):

If the other party are benefiting from your article and you benefit from the backlink, then you cannot have the version of the article on your own website as the original.

This does depend on whether your agreement with the other website includes your ability to post this content elsewhere. It's quite common for hosts of guest posts to expect exclusivity. Before you do this you should check with the other blog, which you'll need to do anyway to get the canonical link back to your own site.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. That makes sense. I think I'll opt to add value to the host's blog, rather than post it again on my site.